# What is the best way to add colors to Material-UI more than Primary/Secondary?

Tags: material-ui

I've looked through the documentation. I've scoured YT for tuts and googled to no avail. Maybe this is just beyond the scope of MUI, but it seems really counter-productive.

I'm just looking for a non-hacky, semantically-correct way of having my color palette defined where components can access the different colors (I know the color prop needs a wrapper, but even a style with the color var is ok to me for this).

My color object is as follows:

```
const colors = {
    cultured: '#FCFAF9',
    darkGray: '#333333',
    turquoise: '#48E5C2',
    unbleachedSilk: '#F3D3BD',
    mediumGray: '#5e5e5e'
}
```

What I'm hoping to achieve is to use the primary/secondary palettes for most of it, but for pop colors, or decorations, I wanted to *add* more colors to the palette without using a semantically-wrong palette object (for instance, using 'error' to set a color, when the object doesn't really represent an error).

Are you *really* relegated to only two main colors with MUI? How are you guys defining 5 colors to use in a way that doesn't break logic?

My idea (pseudo-code):

```
<Button onClick={() => doSomething} color={{colors.mediumGray}} or style={{backgroundColor: colors.mediumGray}}>
Button
</Button>
```

Comment: You can extend the `theme` object with whatever you want, including additional colors. [See documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#adding-new-colors)

Comment: Right, I can add them with no errors, but they do not work in the way that primary/secondary does. How do I access the additional theme colors? Through the classes object? It just seems so needlessly complicated...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You have access to the `theme` object everywhere via `makeStyles` `useTheme`, `withTheme`, `withStyles` `withStyles(styles, { theme: true })`.

Comment: I know. However, you cannot access those newly-created color properties from color props within a component. So if I create a new color called 'custom1' I can't just call <Button color="custom1"> Nothing I try seems to work, either. I'm not sure how to access it without that convoluted wrapper method which seems overly complicated for something as simple as adding a custom color prop.

Comment: Yes, you cannot use it on the `color` prop as a string value (without adding your own custom wrapper). The reason being that the string creates dynamic classes for different components and theme variants, with the correct contrast etc. [See example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.2/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js) I can only guess, but I assume MUI has not opened that up custom colors because of major performance concerns. All that said, I would guess you already use the `classes` and `className` prop extensively and it works just fine there.

Comment: Indeed. I reached out on MUI's repo, and it appears v5 has solved this via color props, and they aim to release this year. I'll just keep using className/classes until v5 drops. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with the repo, it appears that Material UI v5 fixes this issue, and using one of the workarounds is the only way to do it until v5 becomes a stable release (they said sometime in 2021).